# Generating regular expression

Tags: regex, numbers

Can anybody help me to create one regular expression which can check the number has 2 and 4 repeatations of digits like how to check for this no `5555122`.

I want to know by regular expression that there is repeatation of fourth double.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want. Can you give more examples of numbers that would match and numbers that would not?

Comment: `5555` is actually also valid, since it also has a sequence of 4 repetitions and 2 repetition of digit.

Comment: This can certainly be done (the language is regular, as is easy to see), but the resulting expression will be a veritable mess. What do you need this for? Can't you just use a program to check? That probably is simpler, and more understandable (and thus easier to get right).

Comment: Thanks for Answers Friends, i want to create sequence of 7 digit number based on that i have to separate numbers which have repetition of 4 and 2 digits examples are like 1111233 22666623 2231111 9991111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use back reference

```
(\d)\1{3}
```

This would check for repetition of 4 digits

Comment: thanks it worked for triple triple like 4442221 the expression will be like this (\d)(?:(?:\1){3}|(?:\1){3})

Comment: | what is the use of this in regular expression? between ?:(?:\1){3} and ?:(?:\1){3} can we put and also like this?

Comment: @user2021837 when you use `()` anything captured in the group can be referenced in the regex itself using `\1`..`\1` means group1..when you use `(?:)` it says to match anything in it but donot associate it with a number.. so `()` can be referenced with `\1` but `(?:)` cant be referenced with `\1`..so in the current scenario you dont need to use `?:`

Comment: @user2021837 [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) would help you understand

Comment: i used the regular expression which you gave me (\d)(?:(?:\1){3}|(?:\1){2}) but it is not working on number like this 4440222

Comment: you can change the regex to `(\d)(\1{3}|\1{2})`..this would match only 3 repeating digits..what do you want to match..cant understand your problem..explain it with an example

Comment: i want regular expressions for fourthdouble like 5555022 and triple triple like 2220555 and for fifth 6666612 and for fourth triple like 5555888 and for fifth double 1111122 can you please create it for me

Comment: for `fourthdouble`(i guess here you want to match 4 or 2 repeating digits) you can use `(\d)(\1{3}|\1{1})(?!\1)`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
(\d)(?:\1{3}|\1)
```

**explanation**

```
"
(           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \\d          # Match a single digit 0..9
)
(?:         # Match the regular expression below
               # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      \\1          # Match the same text as most recently matched by capturing group number 1
         {3}         # Exactly 3 times
   |           # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      \\1          # Match the same text as most recently matched by capturing group number 1
)
"
```

**EDIT**

Pattern within `(?:\1{3}|\1)`, need a more attention. If it is like `(?:\1|\1{3})` it would not match expected. Because, `The Regex-Directed Engine Always Returns the Leftmost Match`.

Comment: can we put and like this to match both the conditions